A function like ALLEXCEPT but to ignore filters coming from measures
I've got the following measure on a table that basically shows a number, and then a percentage next to it. (I've got also 2 more measures for what I call Month 2 and Month 3 which are just different date ranges)
   Value Month 1 = 
IF(
    ISBLANK([# Failures Month 1]), 
    BLANK(), 
    CALCULATE(
        [# Failures Month 1] & " | " & ((ROUND([% Failures Month 1] * 100 , 2) & "%")),
        ALLEXCEPT('AcuteAll', 'AcuteAll'[Failure Code], 'Asset Location'[Care Setting Description])
    )
)

I have also added a filter to my table based on the following measure where I say, show only values where [# Failures 3 Months] >= 1
# Failures 3 Months = 
IF (
    [# Failures Month 1] >= 1 ||
    [# Failures Month 2] >= 1 ||
    [# Failures Month 3] >= 1,
    1,
    0
)

The problem is that when I filter by [#Failures 3 Months] then [% Failures Month 1] gets all messed up. I've tried adding [# Failures 3 Months] to the ALLEXCEPT on my formula, but because it's a measure and not a column, it won't accept it. What DAX function could I use to ignore the filter on [# Failures 3 months] when calculating my percentage?

Hello, Have you tried the KEEPFILTERS function ?

@AmandineFAURILLOU I believe that KEEPFILTERS also takes a table and column as a parameter and won't accept a measure.

true, I don't have knowledge of such a function. I would integrate your IF inside the ALLEXCEPT, or create a new column altogether.
